# How to pass a date parameter to 2005 SSRS report through URL

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to create a URL link for a report and pass in a date parameter.

The report has an `InDate` parameter that maps to a dropdown populated by a SQL query. The query returns a datetime (value) and an expression (label) that outputs the date value in a `{month}`-`{year}` format. Actual label values that appear in the dropdown are "Jun-2012","Mar-2012", etc. The `InDate` parameter is also used as an input to drive two other date dropdown lists.

The current iteration of the report URL is as follows:

`dadsql04/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fRED+Data+Warehouse/RRMemo&rs%3aCommand=Render&rc%3aParameters=false&InDate=06/30/2012`

When I load the URL I get the following error message:

The `InDate` parameter is missing a value

I have tried using different values for the `InDate` parameter, escaping the slashes, etc. and nothing seems to work. Any help or code sample would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that the InDate parameter was defined as a string instead of a datetime value. Once the parameter was changed from string to datetime the URL worked without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Date parameter format looks good, but the URL you're trying to use is referencing the [Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) component.

Use this [URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to query the report web service directly:

`http://dadsql04/ReportServer?/RED+Data+Warehouse/RRMemo&rc:Parameters=false&InDate=06/30/2012`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I tried this link before. I tried your version and it looks like its redirecting back to dadsql04/ReportServer/Pages/...

Comment: OK, looks like it's just a different way to specify the same report/parameters. I do think the format in the edited link is a bit easier to read. Still having the date problem?

Comment: Just a quick note, in testing I found that parameters are case-sensitive. Please post your RDL file if you can.